# Table creation in php and html

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I'm basically trying to perform a calculation with the first row and first column however I can't seem to get it working correctly.

```
function tableCreator($height_arrayy, $weight_arrayy) {


    echo "<table><tr><th></th>";

    foreach($height_arrayy as $value1) {

        echo "<th>$value1</th>";

    }

    echo "</tr>";



    foreach($weight_arrayy as $value2) {

        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>$value2</td>";

            foreach($weight_arrayy as $value3) {
                foreach($height_arrayy as $value4) {

                echo "<td>" . ($value3) / ( pow( ($value4 / 100), 2 ) ) . "</td>";

                }
            }

        echo "</tr>";


    }

    echo "</table>";



}
```

**Result I am getting:**

[image: This is the result i get]

**Desired Result:**

[image: I want something like this]

Comment: you can do simple round method to reduce the float number length http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 0):

you have added an un-necessary foreach loop, update your second foreach loop as below

```
foreach($weight_arrayy as $value2) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>$value2</th>";
    foreach($height_arrayy as $value4) {
        echo "<td>" . ($value2) / ( pow( ($value4 / 100), 2 ) ) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

your code will return desired output.
use round() if you want to round upto 2 or 3 decimal points.